# Doctrine 2, how to get all joined entity names?

Tags: doctrine-orm

in Doctrine 2, I have a query and a few `->leftJoin()`. How to find out which tables are connected?

EDIT>:

```
$this->createBuilder()->select()->leftJoin('a', 'aEntity')->leftJoin('b', 'bEntity')->getQuery()->execute();
```

and I want to get `aEntity, bEntity`

Comment: It's kind of hard to help you like this. Why don't you share some of your code? What about the query you're talking about?

Comment: You posted this question already [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35508436/doctrine-2-get-joined-entities-from-collection). You shouldn't post the same question again if you don't get any answers. Rather improve the question. Like @FrancescoCasula already mentioned it is not very clear what you want...