# Doctrine 2 get joined entities from collection

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

Here is my query builder:

```
$this
->createBuilder()
->select()
->leftJoin('a', 'aEntity')
->leftJoin('b', 'bEntity')
->getQuery()
->execute();
```

But it can also be like this other one under different circumstances:

```
$this
->createBuilder()
->select()
->leftJoin('a', 'aEntity')
->leftJoin('b', 'bEntity')
->leftJoin('c', 'cEntity')
->getQuery()
->execute();
```

How can I know which entities were joined from the resultset/collection?

Comment: I never had this problem but maybe you can try inspect the collection to find some values of c entity, nulls or not nulls, so as result of the left join always should be something,  but if doctrine remove null entities, event with left join, then I not see a way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Doctrine 2, how to get all joined entity names?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35507834/doctrine-2-how-to-get-all-joined-entity-names)

Comment: What are you asking, exactly?